# Run script for auto connection with wifi

Tags: javascript, python

I receive SSID, password, IP, netmask, DHCP, and DNS on my server. I would like to run a script to connect to wifi with this information. Do you have any suggestions or example to achieve this goal?

I'd like to receive this info -> run from command line ./script.sh ssid password ...
Then script tries to connect to wifi with this informations.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

on a Mac you can use this line of bash in Terminal to log into a wifi network:

```
networksetup -setairportnetwork port networkname password
```

*Note:*

**port** is your wifi port (on my Mac it's port en0)

**networkname** is the name of the network, like Starbucks

**password** is just the straight up password for the network

if the password is already saved in your keychain you don't need that param